# Random password generator with respect to specific string

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, passwords

I need to generate an ID specific random string in Python, i.e. if my ID is `a385446`, I want to generate a random string that can be validated against this ID.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try using the [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) module.

Comment: Is there any chance that i can limit the size of generated hash string to some desired characters ?